# how to implement club post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, membership

New to wordpress I have been assigned to write the code for a club post type where each of the club has number of attributes or e.g. Club Number , Name, Short Name, Division, Region, County
and the staff of the clubs like president, vise president, secretary and 40 other fields. Each of the club is linked to a Division, Region and County

My query is:
How do I implement it in Wordpress i.e. shall I add a custom post type (club) with custom attributes (club staff members) and taxonomies (Division, Region and county) or Shall I create separate custom post types for Division, Region and county and link them with club custom post type. How do I link these post types to each other.

Thanks in Advance

ST

Comment: You are asking for a programming scope on a seemingly larger project.  I'm not trying to be mean here, but if you don't have the knowledge for this, it may be best to hire a programmer who can work with you on the details of this project to make sure it fits the entire scope.  There is not enough details to provide a really good suggestion

Comment: This is quite a broad scope, and there are multiple questions in your question, we have a 1 question per question policy. You need to break your problem down into lots of smaller problems that are easier to research and answer. Remember this isn't a discussion forum, you need a question specific enough that  someone can factually and canonically answer it, for all people with that question, not just what you liked best for your situation

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommand you to use ACF (pro if you can, usefull for the **repeater**) : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

You can easily add custom field and link them to post type, and link post type to each other (this answers your two first questions).

For the third, I guess it will depend how you could implement this

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a plugin recommendation